# 2D to 3D coordinates conversion

Tags: 3d, 2d, webgl, coordinates, computational-geometry

I'm trying to convert geometrical shapes drawn in 2D to 3D. I'm searching for last two days I didn't get any solution how to make it work. Please direct me to a proper way.

For example I have four points to draw a shape, consider (2,2), (4,2), (4,6), (2,0). I managed to connect four points. Now, how it can be converted into 3D shape? Whether it is possible or not?

How the drawn 3D points will be plotted and the shape is been displayed on screen?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add a constant third coordinate to all the points. if that doesnt answer the question you should revise the question to make it more clear what you are asking

Comment: Please give examples, your question is not sufficient as it stands.

Comment: What you're looking for is a [triangulation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, what you need to do is:

**Convert your points into 3D points:**

A(2,2,0), B(4,2,0), C(4,6,0), D(2,0,0)

**Get "duplicate" points with a height:**

E(2,2,1), F(4,2,1), G(4,6,1), H(2,0,1)

**Create triangles from those points: (there might be mistakes in this example)**

```
Front side:
E   EF 
AB   B 

Right side:
F   FG
BC   C

Back side:
G   GH
CD   D

Left side:
D   DA
HE   E

Bottom:
A  AB
CD  D

Top:
E  EF
GH  H
```

=> triangles (EAB),(EBF),(FBC),(FCG),(GCD),(GDH),(DHE),(DEA),(ACD),(ADB),(EGH),(EHF)

**Now all you have to do is draw those triangles.**

=> You get some "cube like" shape

If you have more complex shapes you need triangulation, as LJ_1102 wrote. (at least for top & bottom)

Or of course you can use a Framework like Three.js that does all the work for you:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes